# Unable to call controller method through ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tried all my googling skills , but i am not able to figure out the solution to my problem yet.

I am trying to send parameter to controller method from jquery using ajax. Once method is called, it will render its respective view page. But its not even entering into the ajax code to call the controller method(By inspect). I guess i am doing something really silly , but unable to figure out, Please help me out.

My Controller Method code:

```
def profile 
@prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])
end
```

My .js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "users/profile",
          type: "POST",
          data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
          success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      }
  });
});
    });
```

My routes file:

```
 resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :index,:profile]
  match 'users/profile' => 'users#profile', :as => :profile
```

Comment: hi paritosh ..kindly let me know how to include the logs.. i am newbie to rails.. and is my code right ?

Comment: Are the code inside the table tr click called, have you alert and see,   i thing there may be some problem, please alert and see where is the problem.

Comment: ok...and one quick question ..i want to call method's view i.e.profile.html.erb when our ajax calls the controller method "profile" ...so how to modify it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your routes.rb

```
resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :index]
get 'users/profile/:id' => 'users#profile', :as => :profile
```

And change your js method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "/users/profile/" + $(this).attr('id'),
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

And your method should serialize to json, like this:

```
def profile 
  @prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @proof }
  end
end
```

Comment: still nothing is happening ermin

Comment: hi marvin.. when changing according to your modifications.. now im getting alert messages "[object Object]" whenever i am pressing row in table...what does it mean?

Comment: Well, you are alerting returned object. It depends on what you want to do with returned object. You can access its properties by using data.property_name. You can do console.log(data) instead of alert(data) and check your object structure in console.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tr_class').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "/users/profile?id="+$(this).attr('id'),
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

And your method should serialize to json, like this:

```
def profile 
  @prof = User.where(:id => params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json  { render :json => @proof }
  end
end
```

Comment: hi soni.. when changing according to above comment's modifications.. now im getting alert messages "[object Object]" whenever i am pressing row in table...what does it mean?